# 301 redirect works in browser, but tools checkers say it's still a 200 response

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I've been having a few problems switching a website from HTTP to HTTPS. The problem appears when I redirect via .htaccess.

If I type "http://abcfoto.ro/ce-este-profunzimea-de-camp-depth-field-15/" in browser the correct page is loaded, but when I do check the redirect code with the available online tools it shows as still pointing to the http page and gives a 200 code.

Some pages don't have this issue (homepage, search page) and do redirect also in browser and in the online tools with a 301 code. I've tested with pretty much every tool on the first Google page where I've searched for "redirect checker".

I've tried both solutions found online for .htaccess and both work the same way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abcfoto.ro [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abcfoto.ro [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://abcfoto.ro/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Any ideas would be appreciated to fix this mess. Thanks!

Comment: `http://abcfoto.ro/ce-este-profunzimea-de-camp-depth-field-15/` redirects me to `https://abcfoto.ro/ce-este-profunzimea-de-camp-depth-field-15/` - and _that one_ then says 404 Not Found …?

Comment: Seems to happen on first call only, after reloading `https://abcfoto.ro/ce-este-profunzimea-de-camp-depth-field-15/` I get to see the content.

Comment: I've changed the order of the code in .htacces. It seems to work with: the second rule then wordpress rule. The rule where you replace the sitename.com and www.sitename.com doesn't work at all for some reason.